# What are the IDEs for developing .Net Core application?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, .net-core

I'm want to learn .net core application development. I'm currently using `Visual Studio 2012`.

> Is there a way to develop a .net core application with Visual Studio 2012 or is it
>   compulsory to use `Visual Studio 2017` for .net core development ?

Comment: You can do it with Notepad.  You'll learn more, but it is going to take a lot longer and you may well give up early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We can develop .Net core application using several applications or methods.**

1. Command Prompt

> We can use command prompt to develop .net core application and the
>   additional thing we want is .net core SDK. You can follow [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-first-console-application-using-command-prompt-in-net-core-2-0/).

2. Visual Studio Code

> You can use visual studio code for .net core development which is
>   light application that can be taken for free. follow [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-with-asp-net-core-mvc-using-visual-studio-code-and-ado-net/) article.

3. Visual Studio 2017 community version

> This is also a way to develop .net core application which comes with
>   many facilities. after registering you can use this one also for free. Follow [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/getting-started-angular-in-net-core-2).

Answer (score 7):

According [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x), if you want to develop .NET Core apps on Windows, you have three options:

- [Command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-with-xplat-cli) with any editor of your choice (it can be VS 2012 as well)
- [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) (Microsoft has no intentions to support earlier versions of VS for .Net Core development) - it also has Community Edition
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) for easy cross-platform development, best fit for ASP.NET Core apps

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com).

Comment: Why one **should** use the `Code` if Visual studio is available for him? You should elaborate on that

Comment: IMHO development of web application became more easy with a lightweight editor. And its' free.

Comment: Community Edition is free as well, as OP asking about *learning* the .Net Core development